# jQuery ui effect drop is fading

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

Instead of dropping in and out of the scene. The element stays put and fades out instead of dropping like it's suppose to...

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("button").click(function () {
        $(".target").hide("drop", {
            direction: "up"
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

and

```
   <button>Show</button> 
   <div class="target">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/EwHWLHV.png" alt="SO" />
   </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pGv7R/

Comment: works fine here ?? http://jsfiddle.net/pGv7R/1/

Comment: You have a problem with jQuery UI file version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use different versions. Eg:- jQuery 1.11.1 + jQuery UI 1.9.2